# Deleting all special characters from a string - ruby

Tags: ruby, special-characters

I was doing the challenges from [pythonchallenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com) writing code in ruby, [specifically this one](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html). It contains a really long string in page source with special characters. I was trying to find a way to delete them/check for the alphabetical chars.

I tried using scan method, but I think I might not use it properly. I also tried `delete!` like that:

```
    a = "PAGE SOURCE CODE PASTED HERE"
    a.delete! "!", "@"  #and so on with special chars, does not work(?) 
    a
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can do this

```
a.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

Answer (score 21):

try with gsub

```
a.gsub!(/[!@%&"]/,'')
```

try the regexp on rubular.com

if you want something more general you can have a string with valid chars and remove what's not in there:

```
a.gsub!(/[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ]/,'')
```

Comment: I think this `[^A-Za-z ]` works better, in this case. Otherwise, if you have a sentence, which typically **should** start with a capital letter, you will lose your capital letters. You would also lose any `1337 speak`, or other possible crypts within the text.

Case in point:

`phrase = "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."
=> "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."`

Answer (score 9):

When you give multiple arguments to [`string#delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-delete), it's the intersection of those arguments that is deleted. `a.delete! "!", "@"` deletes the intersections of the sets `!` and `@` which means that nothing will be deleted and the method returns `nil`.

What you wanted to do is `a.delete! "!@"` with the characters to delete passed as a single string.

Since the challenge is asking to clean up the mess and find a message in it, I would go with a whitelist instead of deleting special characters. The delete method accepts ranges with `-` and negations with `^` (similar to a regex) so you can do something like this: `a.delete! "^A-Za-z "`.

You could also use regular expressions as shown by @arieljuod.

Answer (score 6):

`gsub` is one of the most used Ruby methods in the wild.

```
specialname="Hello!#$@"
cleanedname = specialname.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/,"")
```

Comment: This still keeps the "-" btw

Answer (score 5):

I think `a.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/, '')` works better in this case. Otherwise, if you have a sentence, which typically **should** start with a capital letter, you will lose your capital letter. You would also lose any `1337 speak`, or other possible crypts within the text.

Case in point:

`phrase = "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."
=> "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."`

`phrase.gsub(/[^a-z ]/, '')
=> "oe cant tell between large and large"`

`phrase.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/, '')
=> "Joe cant tell between large and large"`

`phrase2 = "W3 a11 f10a7 d0wn h3r3!"
phrase2.gsub(/[^a-z ]/, '')
=> " a fa dwn hr"`

`phrase2.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/, '')
=> "W3 a11 f10a7 d0wn h3r3"`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the original string - i.e. to solve the challenge.

```
str.each_char do |letter|
  if letter =~ /[a-z]/  
    p letter    
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write down your own string sanitize function, could easily use `regex` and the `gsub` method.

Atomic sample:

```
your_text.gsub!(/[!@\[;\]^%*\(\);\-_\/&\\|$\{#\}<>:`~"]/,'')
```

API sample:

Route: `post 'api/sanitize_text', to: 'api#sanitize_text'`

Controller:

```
  def sanitize_text
    return render_bad_request unless params[:text].present? && params[:text].present?
    sanitized_text = params[:text].gsub!(/[!@\[;\]^%*\(\);\-_\/&\\|$\{#\}<>:`~"]/,'')
    render_response( {safe_text: sanitized_text})
  end
```

Then you call it

```
POST /api/sanitize_text?text=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456<>$!@%23^%26*[]:;{}()`,.~'"\|/
```